# form keydown event interrupt the working of textBox keypress event c#

Tags: c#

I have a form, where I am using Form_keyDown Event and KeyPreview=true.

The code is as follows

```
private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
            button2_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
            button3_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
            button4_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
            button5_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
            button6_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            button7_Click(sender, e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
            button8_Click(sender, e);
    }
```

But when I press the keys (i.e. C,P,B,U,T,W and X) on a textBox the event fires. What I need is the Skip the TextBox from Form_keyDown event. Is this possible?

The Function keys are already in use and the user does not prefer to user alt or ctrl.

Is there is any away to form_keyDown event and textBox KeyPress works differently?

Comment: try `if(sender is TextBox) e.Handled=true;`

Comment: Or `if(!(sender is Form)) { e.Handled = true; return; }`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  The Sender is always "Form", in my case MainForm. So those Code are not working

Comment: @IanH. The Sender is always "Form", in my case MainForm. So those Code are not working

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  I got the answer, Thanks for you help

Comment: @IanH.  I got the answer, Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveControl.Name!="textBox20")
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
                button2_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
                button3_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
                button4_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U)
                button5_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.T)
                button6_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                button7_Click(sender, e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
                button8_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
```